# Cannot call web api 2 post method with int parameter in URL in Unit Test using Http server

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api2

Please ignore the spelling mistake, I cannot copy code so I have typed the whole thing and changed name of controller and method.

WEB API 2

Controller:

```
// Controller name is Test
public HttpResponseMessage Method1(int param1)   // Post method
{
    // return string
}
```

If I create an object of controller in test case then it is working fine. But if I want to test in localhost using following code:

Unit Test:

```
public void Method1Test()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}");
    HttpServer server = new HttpServer(config);
    using(var client = new HttpClient(server))
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost:5022/api/test?param1=1");
        request.Content = new ObjectContent<int>(param1, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
        response = client.SendAsync(request, CancellationToken.None).Result;
    };
Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
}
```

Now, my test case is failing. I used the same code in different project and it worked. May be it is the way I am trying to call Post method. Is this the right way to call post method with Int parameter in URL?

In help page, under API column it shows:

```
POST api/test/param1={param1}
```

Also I have put some stop point in actual service I am cursor is not stopping at that point. Why?

If I want to call the same service from browser, what URL should I pass? Is it -

```
http://localhost:5022/api/test?param1=1
```

Or something else?

Comment: what error are you getting when you are saying test case is failing?

Comment: In Test Case:
Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<OK>. Acutal:<NotFound>.
And when I pass the link in Browser:
The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Following is the correct unit test method but this has some extra information which I have not provided earlier i.e., passing object as an input for the service.

```
private void Method1Test(ObjectClass obj)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}");
    HttpServer server = new HttpServer(config);
    using (var client = new HttpClient(server))
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost:5022/api/test/1");
        request.Content = new ObjectContent<ObjectClass>(obj, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
        response = client.SendAsync(request, CancellationToken.None).Result;
    };
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
}
```

So the correct URL that I was looking for was

```
http://localhost:5022/api/test/1
```

Sorry, It took long to post this answer. This method is working like a charm for more then 2 years.